# Syntax error in Matlab MatConvNet vl_nnconv function implemented as Pytorch nn.conv1d function

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

In Matlab, I have the following code:

```
x = vl_nnconv(x, 'size', [3 3 3 nfilters(i)], 'pad', 1);
```

When I do the same thing in Python (Pytorch), I get a syntax error:

```
for i in range(1, nlayers-1):
    if i == 1:
        x = nn.conv1d(x,[3 3 3 nfilters(i)], pad())
```

with the error marked at the `[3 3 3 nfilters(i)]` area. I'm not sure what is the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The proper formatting for the functional API [`F.conv1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.conv1d.html#torch.nn.functional.conv1d) (where `F` is `torch.nn.functional`) is:

```
F.conv1d(x, weight, bias=None, stride=1, padding=0)
```

Assuming you have `weight` (and optionally `bias`) as tensors stored somewhere.